# How to get the children of a Relative Layout after Dragging them?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, get-childitem

I have a RelativeLayout in Android platform. The order of Views looks like the following picture( sports ,Airplane ,Flying ,Travel )
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK4xq.jpgh)
I change the location of the views by Drag them:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ParamV = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
              int idV = (Integer) v.getId();
              if (idV == MainActivity.count)
                  return true;
              if (idV == 100) {
                  MainActivity.BtDel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded);
                  return true;
              }
              BtT.setLayoutParams(ParamV);
              BtT.setId(idV);
              v.setLayoutParams(ParamB);
              v.setId(idB);
              ParamB = ParamV;
              idB = idV;
              return true;
```

After changing the location, I have the following picture:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuJuH.jpg)

I use the following code to get children of Layout:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        Button Bt = (Button) layout.getChildAt(i);
        CharSequence St = Bt.getText();
        sb.append(St);
        if (i < layout.getChildCount() - 1)
            sb.append(",");
    }
```

But the result is exactly like the first picture althouth the location of views is changed.
What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The location might be changed, but their order will always stay the same.
You should consider using a different layout, perhaps a GridLayout.

I noticed something too - never ever put a static reference to a view in an activity. Not only is it bad programming, your view(s) will never be garbage-collected, and your app will have some serious memory leak.

Comment: I don't have any more choose. I have to use Relative Layout and sole the problem. How can I change their orders too?